# Is there a JavaScript port of the functions in the C standard library?

Tags: javascript, c

I am porting some C code to JavaScript. I would like to not have to implement basic functions like `strcspn` myself

```js
const strcspn = (a, b) => {
  for (let [index, c] of [...a].entries()) {
    if (b.includes(c)) {
      return index
    }
  }
  return a.length
}
```

Is there a project I can copy them from or that I could import?

Comment: The function you show is not exactly like the `strcspn` function. If the character is not found you return `a.length` which will be an invalid index in a Javascript string.

Answer (score 1):

There is no library in Javascript that provides the same functions of the C Standard Library (that I'm aware of, at least).

So you have to rewrite the functions yourself (not particularly difficult, as Javascript has many builtins that may help you).

**Better yet**: *don't* use C standard functions in Javascript: modify the C code directly in order to write more idiomatic Javascript code. What I mean:

```js
// a C code that uses `strtok()` to split a string may be rewritten in JS as:
const splitted = str.split(" ");
// it's cleaner and you don't need to rewrite `strtok()` in JS
```

---

NOTE: your implementation of `strcspn()` is wrong. The correct implementation in Javascript would be:

```js
function strcspn(dest, src) {
  let res = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < dest.length; i += 1) {
    if (src.includes(dest.charAt(i))) {
      break;
    }
    res += 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```